# WordPress jQuery uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a function in my jQuery for my wordpress site. It's in my main.js and above document.ready and my main.js is being loaded after jQuery loads.

Everything works in my static version of the site, it doesn't work when I try to implement it in my theme in wordpress

The function:

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find("i.indicator")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom glyphicon-triangle-left');
}

$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

It gives this error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

When I try to replace the `$` with `jQuery` I get no errors in my console but it doesn't work. Anyone knows what's going on here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is this code on the page? does it execute after jQuery is loaded?

Comment: If you run the `.on()` calls before the element with id "accordion" is in the DOM, you'll get no errors but the calls won't do anything.

Comment: If the `jQuery` variable works but the `$` does not it means that another plugin has taken the `$` reference away from jQuery or that you've used `$.noConflict()` somewhere. Either way, we can't help you find where in your code that might be.

Comment: @YarGnawh Yes it's my main.js and my main.js is loaded after jQuery is loaded. I should add that all my other jQuery does work. I edited OP.

Comment: @Pointy I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: The page is interpreted top to bottom. If your code is in a `<script>` block in the `<head>` of the document, then `$("#accordion")` will find nothing. That won't be treated as an error because that's just how jQuery works.

Comment: @Pointy My main.js is being loaded at the bottom of the page

Comment: I dont' work with wordpress, but it seems common for jQuery to be in NoConflict mode with wordpress. Tons of possible dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112558/jquery-script-fails-to-load-in-wordpress-is-not-a-function

Comment: OK well if there are no errors when you switch to `jQuery` instead of `$`, then the issue is that the id of the target element really isn't "accordion", or that the "hidden" and "shown" events are never being fired. Those events aren't native browser events, so that means they're coming from some other package or plugin I guess? You could verify that those are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're scripts are loading in the correct order, if your website is using jQuery in noconflict mode you have two choices:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // Your code here
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Or

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Your code here
});
```

Comment: It's working for my new feature, but all of the old features aren't working anymore...
Even if is in different script or in my html... :/